# Least and most significant bit calculation using bitwise operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary

I am working on a project and I need to calculate the least significant bit (LSB) and most significant bit (MSB) of integers.

Suppose $x$ is an $n$-bit unsigned integer ($n=16, 32$ or $64$). We know that $y=x \ \& \ ($~$x+1)$ clears all the bits of $x$ except for the LSB. This is lightning fast, just three operations. Is there something similar for the MSB? What is the fastest way to compute it?

Comment: If $x=2$, then $x \& (x+1) = 2$, so it does not clear all the bits. The most significant bit stays as $1$.

Comment: @Daniel Beale Yes, sorry, it is ~$x$ instead of $x$. The negation of $x$. I have changed it.

Comment: Have a look at this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i).

Comment: You might have thought that would work, but addition can carry from one bit to the next. The bitwise and operates on each bit independently. This means that $\&$ does not distribute over $+$. Again, if $x=2$ then $x\&(\sim x + 1) = 2$.

Comment: Usually to extract a bit at a particular location we use a `bit mask' with a one in the location that needs to be extracted.

Comment: @Daniel Beale I agree, the + operation could be more than one cycle. Can you come up with a faster way? I am with you if you can. And yes, that's right for $x=2$ because the LSB is the second one which by accident happens to be $x$ itself. I know about bit masks, how do you know which bit to extract, you have to go through a while loop to do that.

Comment: @Daniel Beale In fact all powers of 2 have exactly one bit "on" and so that bit is the LSB (and the MSB for that matter) of the number. Anyhow, this is a question about MSB not LSB.

Comment: So, $y = x \& 1$ retrieves the LSB of $x$ and $y = x \& (1 << N - 1) $ retrieves the MSB where $N$ is the number of bits, and $<<$ is the bitshift operator. Of course, it would be faster to hard code $1 << N - 1$ if you know what $N$ is.

Comment: There is a source of confusion here. You are refering to the first bit and the last bit. I am referring to the right-most bit that is "on" (the LSB) and the leftmost bit that is "on". For example the if $x=00101110$, the LSB is the second (from the right) and the MSB is the sixth. I know this terminology is confusing but that's what I mean. Otherwise it's very simple as you wrote.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027878/algorithm-to-find-the-most-significant-bit

Comment: Isn't the MSB always $1$?  Are you looking for the position it is in?

Comment: The most significant bit (MSB) is the position of the left-most bit that is "on". Similarly for the LSB. Terminology differs but that's what it is in the current context.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just came across this hack from an old book about chess programming:

$$
y=XOR(x,x-1)=00...001111...11,
$$

where the leftmost $1$ in $y$ is the leftmost $1$ of $x$, ie the MSB of $x$. Then we can add $1$ and shift right by $1$. I am not an expert but I think it's faster than what we 've seen here.

Comment: Hey, that's a lie, isn't it? It returns the rightmost bit ie the LSB, **not** the MSB ??!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way that works in $\log(|n|)$ where |n| is the number of bits needed to represent $n$.
Let's say we have a 32-bit integers.

```
MST(int x)
{
    x|=(x>>1);
    x|=(x>>2);
    x|=(x>>4);
    x|=(x>>8);
    x|=(x>>16);
    x++;
    x>>=1;
    return x;
}
```

The reason why this works is that the first 5 lines set all bits right to the mst to 1. By adding one to the number we flip them all (including mst) to zero and put a one the left of them all. we shift this one to the right (and hence it's now in the position of mst) and return the number.

Comment: With the obvious generalization for 64-bit I guess..

Comment: You’re right we only add the line “x|=(x>>32)”